# In how many ways $n$ couples can be seated on a bench so that..

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> In how many ways $n$ couples can be seated on a bench so that...
>
> every wife seats next to her husband?

I came to take every couple as one object so $n!$ and $2^n$ for switching seats betwen wife and husband or husband and wife so at the end $n!*2^n$

> no wife will sit next to her husband?

I did all the possibilities - the possibilities each wife seats to her husband
then we get possibilities of the wife not seating next to her husband
$2n!- (n!2^n)$

But I am doubting my answers, am I wrong?

Comment: The first one looks right to me. The second is wrong. YOu are substracting for all possible arrangements those from the first point (every wife seats next to her husband) but you are including the arrangement with some (less than $n$) couples together.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer for the first part is correct.

We can do the second part using the principle of inclusion and exclusion.  How many ways are there for $k$ couples to sit together?  There are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to choose the couples, and then $k!$ ways to arrange them in order, and then we can seat them in $2^k$ ways.  We can arrange the remaining people in order in $(2n-2k)!$ ways.  There are $k+1$ spaces around the distinguished $k$ couples in which to place the other people, and by stars and bars, there $\binom{2n-2k+k}{k}=\binom{2n-k}{k}$ ways to distribute them.

By inclusion and exclusion, the total number of ways is $$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}k!2^k(2n-2k)!\binom{2n-k}{k}=\\\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(2n-k)!2^k$$

Computing the first few values, and plugging them into OESI, we find [A007060](http://oeis.org/A007060).